# for loop or for-in loop

Tags: javascript

This is a function in the Modernizr.js.
http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/annotatedsource.html#section-21

Function test_props accepts props which is an array, then iterates it using a for-in loop.
My question is: since props is an array, it has a length property. And normal for loop is faster than for-in loop. Why using for-in loop?

```
function test_props( props, callback ) {
        for ( var i in props ) {
            if ( m_style[ props[i] ] !== undefined && ( !callback || callback( props[i], modElem ) ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `props` is an array, they probably shouldn't be using `for..in`. If that's an object, `for..in` is fine.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use a for in loop in general and it should be avoided as much as possible. There are cases where it can’t be avoid for instance if you are iterating though a JSON object.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It's no use to iterate over JSON object, it's a global native JS object...